# change selected option by a variable

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class='titlewrap' data-status = 'public'>PUBLIC</div>
<div class='titlewrap' data-status = 'private'>PRIVATE</div>

<select id='selstatus'>
<option value = 'public'>PUBLIC</option>
<option value = 'private'>PRIVATE</option>
</select>
```

**JS Code**

I need to change selected option by value of the `data status` of clicked `titlewrap`.

Something like

```
$('.titlewrap').click(function(){
    var status = $(this).data('status');
    $('#selstatus').selectedOption(status);
});
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the value of select using `.val()`

```js
$('.titlewrap').click(function() {
  var status = $(this).data('status');
  $('#selstatus').val(status);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='titlewrap' data-status='public'>PUBLIC</div>
<div class='titlewrap' data-status='private'>PRIVATE</div>

<select id='selstatus'>
<option value = 'public'>PUBLIC</option>
<option value = 'private'>PRIVATE</option>
</select>
```